# Graphics parameter 'algebraic'undefined in Texmaker

Tags: pstricks

I am trying to run the following beamer class file containging some PStricks codes (generated by Geogebra) in the sequence Latex+Dvips+ps2pdf+viewpdf in Texmaker (for Ubuntu 12.04):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}%NICe
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=white!100}%}, fg=black!100}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Sample}
\begin{block}{Sample}
\begin{figure}[h]
\psset{xunit=0.2cm,yunit=0.2cm,algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-26.85,-7.45)(50.42,28.24)
\psline(-26,10)(-14,10)
\psline(-14,10)(-2,16)
\psline(-26,4)(-14,4)
\psline(-14,10)(-2,4)
\end{pspicture*}
\end{figure}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But when I compile this code, Texmaker gives me the following error message :

```
"! Graphics parameter `algebraic' not defined..
\@pstrickserr ... immediate help.}\errmessage {#1}
\endgroup
l.187 \end{frame}"
```

I can't understand what could be the problem. I need some help !

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the proper package version, or the package isn't linked to `texmaker` properly.

Comment: ya most probably. All these days I had used texmaker in Windows and there was an option to install missing packages in Miktex but in Linux, Miktex is not required. So how do I install missing packages here? Do you have any idea about it ?

Comment: Installing packages (http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=installing+packages) and updating packages (http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=updating+packages) depend on what TeX distribution you have installed. There's a search function at the top right corner of the site that will allow you to search existing answers on the subject - The general outline of installation (for me) is: - download `.sty` off CTAN; - create a directory in your tex distribution at the right location (for me its `/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/`); - run `texhash` in your command prompt/command line. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`algebraic=true` option is used to let us write the math expression in infix form. `algebraic=false` which is default prompts as to write the math expression in postfix form (aka Reverse Polish Notation or RPN for short).

In your code below, `algebraic` option is not needed because no part in your code need infix math expression. Just remove the `algebraic=true`. Also remove `\usepackage{pstricks}` as you did it twice.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}%NICe
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=white!100}%}, fg=black!100}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Sample}
\begin{block}{Sample}
\begin{figure}[h]
\psset{xunit=0.2cm,yunit=0.2cm,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-26.85,-7.45)(50.42,28.24)
\psline(-26,10)(-14,10)
\psline(-14,10)(-2,16)
\psline(-26,4)(-14,4)
\psline(-14,10)(-2,4)
\end{pspicture*}
\end{figure}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]